# Proof if $(x_n)$ is bounded sequence, then it converges $\iff$ $\limsup(x_n)=\liminf(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I have proved this theorem, can somebody check? So

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence, then $(x_n)$ convergegs if and only if $\limsup(x_n)=\liminf(x_n)$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ "$\Rightarrow$" Let $(x_n)$ converges to $x$. So $\exists \ N_1 \ \in \ \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|< \epsilon \ \forall \ n\geq N_1$. So we have that $x-\epsilon<x_n<x+\epsilon$. Hence $x-\epsilon<x_n$ for infinite number $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$, then $x=\limsup(x_n)$ (by definition of $\limsup$). On the other hand we have $x_n<x+\epsilon$ for infinite number $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$, then $x=\liminf(x_n)$ (by definition of $\liminf$).

Another direction was much easier, therefore I need help only with 1 direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the basic idea, but I find it easier to go from these definitions:
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf_{m\geqslant n} x_m\\
\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{m\geqslant n} x_m.
\end{align}
So if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $$x-\varepsilon < \inf_{m\geqslant N}x_m < \sup_{m\geqslant N}x_m<x+\varepsilon,$$ and hence these quantities are equal.

Comment: thank you for your answer) but my proof is correct, isn;t ?

Comment: Hmm, I believe you have the definitions of $\inf$ and $\sup$ mixed up. That is, the statements regarding  $x-\varepsilon<x_n$ and $x_n<x+\varepsilon$ should be switched.